# img var onClick Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, onclick, var

I want to make an onclick on this var imageCatuaba

```
function setCatuaba(map) {
  var imageCatuaba = {
    url: 'images/catuskov.1.png',
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  };
```

Onclick jquery function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(var imageCatuaba).click(function(){
        $('.boxBAR').css('display','block')
    })
});
```

Comment: How do you expect a user to "click" on a *variable*?  What you're trying to do makes no sense.

Comment: Look at this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple, It demonstrates an onclick for a marker, it should work the same with an image

Comment: If you're using angular you should avoid using jQuery as much as possible because chances are the framework already contains a directive that handles whatever it is you're trying to do with jQuery.  In this case you should use the ng-click directive.

Answer (score -1):

if it can help i don't know if a variable can be embeded in a $(). something

```js
$("#imageCatuaba").click(function(){
  $('.boxBAR').css('display','block')
});
```

```css
div {
 background-color: lightblue;
 width: 100px;
}

.boxBar {
 display: inline; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="boxBar">
  <p>box</p>
</div>

<div id="imageCatuba">
  <img src=""></img>
</div>
```